# onClick on MenuItem not fired

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

I am using redux form with material ui. I have an array of form templates that are available to select as options. What I am trying to achieve is to get the selected template back, dispatch an action and then initialize redux form with selected template values. I am unable to call the method on SelectItem component (nothing gets logged to the console). I went through the similar problems and solutions but nothing seemed to work in my case. My code goes like this:

```
  setTemplate = (option) => {
console.log(option);}



        {formTemplates && (
      <Row>
        <StyledFormControl>
          <Field name="templates" label="Available templates:" component={SelectField}>
            <MenuItem value="" disabled>
              Choose template:
            </MenuItem>
            {formTemplates.map(option => {
              return (
                <MenuItem value={option._id} onClick={this.setTemplate.bind(this, option)} key={option._id}>
                  {option._id}
                </MenuItem>
              );
            })}
          </Field>
        </StyledFormControl>
      </Row>
    )}
```

Do you have any idea why this should not work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try 
`onClick={() => this.setTemplate(option).bind(this)}`

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining where in the code the Original Poster should use this, what it is and why it would help. There is not enough context for this to be useful.